# Reduction of general conic

Tags: algebraic-geometry, conic-sections

The given equation is -
$$3x^2 + 2xy + 3y^2 - 32y +92=0$$

To get rid of xy term i used the substitutions -
$$x=p+q , y=q-p$$

Then the equation becomes -
$$(p-4)^2 + 2(q-2)^2=1$$
which is an ellipse with center at $p=4$ and $q=2$.

So in the original system , $x=p+q=6$ and $y=q-p=-2$ .

But the actual center as wolfram alpha shows is the opposite , that is $x=-2$ and $y=6$.

I don't know why this is happening and i'm really confused.

Please help.

Comment: Why don't we use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_of_axes#Elimination_of_the_xy_term_by_the_rotation_formula

Comment: @labbhattacharjee I found on this site about the method i used - http://www.geom.uiuc.edu/docs/reference/CRC-formulas/node28.html  also can't we use any substitution to get rid of xy term as long as we finally convert our answers to original sytem?

Comment: Start by testing if the equation that you got after substituting $x=p+q$, $y=q-p$ is correct.

Comment: @lsp got it , i feel ashamed , thanks.

Comment: @AGoogler Things happen all the time. No need to worry

Comment: @labbhattacharjee is it allowed to use any substitution to get rid of xy term as long as we finally convert our answers to original system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**

I did what you tell $(x=p+q , y=q-p)$ and the raw result I obtained  for the expression is $$4 p^2+32 p+8 q^2-32 q+92=0$$ I let you the task of grouping but it seems that you made some mistakes.

I am sure that you can take from here and fix the problem.

Comment: Wow i'm an idiot . Thanks and sorry for wasting your time. One more question , can we use any substitution to get rid of xy term as long as we finally convert our answers to original sytem? If so , why is rotation method as given in wikipedia (see lab's comment) preferred?

Comment: You are not an idiot ! You made a mistake. If I was given a dollar for each mistake I made in my loooong life, I should be a billionaire !! When  lab bhattacharjee makes a recommendation, just go that way.